# Issue in adding images dynamically to TextView

Tags: android, textview

Below is my `Activity` `Layout` XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this below is the code which I use within my `Activity`

```
    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
    appendDrawable(tView,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    appendText(tView,R.string.message);
    }
```

and the methods are :

```
private void appendDrawable(TextView tView, int drawableId) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    String THREE_SPACES = "   ";
    builder.append(THREE_SPACES);
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan image = new ImageSpan(drawable);      
    builder.setSpan(image, 1,  2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tView.append(builder);  
}

private void appendText(TextView tView, int stringId) {
    tView.append(getResources().getString(stringId));
}
```

and the output which I got is not what I expected
3 missing
[image: output from Nexus]

and if I tilt the screen
1 missing
[image: output from Nexus]

Can anyone help me in finding out why the images went missing and if there is a better way of doing this.

Expected Output : As per the loop it should display (drawable, Hello World)15 times  but in this example the drawable wasn't rendered thrice(and once when I tilted). Some issues with wrapping?

Comment: What did you expect this to do?

Comment: every 2 messages should be separated by the drawable . This doesn't always happen

Comment: So you mean to say that it should be two messages, then a drawable, then two messages, then the drawable again, and etc.?

Comment: I have updated the question. It should be first drawable, first message, second drawable second message and so on.But as you can see some of the drawables are missing.In this example 2 out of 15 aren't displayed.

Comment: sorry,3 out of 15 are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
builder.setSpan(image, 1,  2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

should be

```
builder.setSpan(image, 0,  3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

since you're using 3 spaces as your span range

Comment: Thanks, that was the culprit. I was trying to add an additional space before and after the drawable but seems it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to accept the answer as the solution :)

Comment: how could i add image between text instead of at end of text??? tahnks in advance